# SQL Select only the first row

Tags: sql

I am desesperate about an SQL select. I have one table which has 4 parameters: id, country, address and price. That table has the same id for a lot of rows and I am trying to obtain the sum of the prices for each id. For example, if I have the next data:

```
ID  Country  Address  Price
1   France   Address1 1000
1   France   Address2 3332
1   France   Address1 1562
1   France   Address3 1123
1   France   Address2 1123
2   UK       Address8 1234
2   UK       Address7 1233
```

I want to obtain the next result:

```
ID  Country  Address  Price
1   France   Address1 SUM(1000, 3332, 1562, 1123, 1123)
2   UK       Address8 SUM(1234, 1233)
```

I have tried a lot of queries but I can't obtain that result. The problem is that I obtain the data grouped by country and address and, as I have different address, I obtain multiple rows with, for example, the three addresses of France.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my english level.

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? Also what do you mean by first address? which address the max or the min? the rows aren't stored with a specific order in the table, so you have to specify what the order do you want to select the first row based on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without know how you sort your Address, one cannot tell what is considered as the First Address row. If it is sorted in ascending order, then:

```
SELECT   [ID], Country, MIN(Address), SUM(Price) As TotalPrice
FROM     tblYourTableName
GROUP BY [ID], Country
ORDER BY [ID]
```

If it is not, then you will need to implement a subquery to sort the address by ID & Country.  Need to know more.

Comment: I have tried but I have the same problem. I only want to obtain one row for each id but, as I have multiple addresses, I obtain multiple rows.

Comment: Sorry I forget to use MIN. That works. Thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works

```
SELECT country, SUM(price)
FROM table
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer changes according to your DBMS. For example:

```
SELECT   [ID], Country, Address, SUM(Price) As TotalPrice
FROM     tblYourTableName
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY [ID]
```

This query doesn't work on Sql Server, Oracle but works on MySql.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to the query is this one

```
select a.ID, a.Country, a.Address, sum(a.Price) as TotalPrice
from address a
group by a.ID;
```

but as the other said, we need to know how you want to sort the address in relation to the Country to have the proper output.

Another important thing is the DBMS.

By the Way, check this SQLFiddle if you want to test it quickly http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61ba6/4

You can even change the DBMS so you are 100% sure that the Query will work.